# Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger in Android Studio

Tags: android

`Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger`

I am getting this error in the Event Log.
the app works but i don't get any thing at the Run

is there something that i can do to fix it

Comment: Please check this post if you are using windows machine
https://androidforums.com/threads/error-cant-bind-to-local-8600-for-debugger.1039499/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by restarting the computer. i am not sure that this is the best way to do it but it worked for me